# Why aren't local requests almost instant?

Tags: ubuntu, performance, slow-connection, network-speed

This is purely out of curiosity, but with every local server I've ever setup, there has always been a 0.5-2 second delay until pages are displayed.

Just as an example, I've setup a completely blank ubuntu server running apache, mysql and php. If I have a file with phpinfo(); in and request that from a machine sitting literally next to the server, the page will still take a second or two to load. Why isn't it [almost] instant?

Both machines are running quad core processors, 8gb ram etc using a gigabit switch. Why would a simple request like phpinfo take so long to 'happen'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be a number of things influencing the time it takes to display it. If there's any code at all, it still has to be interpreted and run. DNS lookups still occur, so there's a delay in that (unless you have them all localhost lookups.) Rendering by the browser. The overhead of the protocol.

If you're interested you can run wireshark and see the network side of the overhead of lookups and protocol.

Everything else would come from the time it takes the server to process the request and your client to render the response.

Answer (score 2):

Try benchmarking with ab:

```
ab -c 1 -n 1 http://your.server/page/
```

phpinfo() uses some resources and takes some time, and browser rendering takes some time too. Serving a static (short) html page took me 5ms on a gigabit LAN.

PS: modern browsers are really slow :/

Comment: Is there a windows equivalent to the ab command? All of my client machines are running windows at the moment. Judging by the answers here it looks like I've been incredibly ignorant in assuming the connection is the slowest part of the process. Ah well, you don't ask, you don't learn!

Comment: afaik it's bundle with apache (windows version too)... maybe you can somehow unpack the apache .msi and extract just the ab.exe binary, so you wouldn't have to install the whole apache just for the benchmark.

Comment: 7-Zip should do the trick for extracting.

Comment: Never ocurred to me that I would already have it since I run xampp on my windows machines. /xampp/apache/bin/ab.exe

Comment: @mulaz - I'm getting very fast response times for plain html, so you're right!

Answer (score 2):

1.)  The first hit on the server and the first invocation of the PHP script in question is actually causing a number of configurations to be parsed, interpreters (possibly) loaded, scripts loaded, modules in the web server coming online, etc.  In subsequent queries it's almost invariably faster.

2.) Even under ideal conditions there are a number of moving parts in play during your 0.5 - 2 sec - between your machine going through the setup of several TCP sessions (each requiring a few msec of handshaking), your browser identifying itself and working out capabilities with the server, your browser finally submitting its request and then the server having to parse that information and pass it up and down the stack to then finally format it into HTML to send back to you.

There's quite a bit of sophistication in the implementation of modern scripting / web platforms.  It may seem a bit heavy when compared to pinging a server or putting up a static "Hello world!" html page, but the generalized capabilities are pretty impressive.

The other point, of course, is that you're describing a completely stock system.  There are almost always things that can be done to tune it to better respond to your particular workload.